# SQL Server - Using two aggregate functions to create a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, case

I'm trying to create three columns that show the average monthly purchase amount for a customer. The three columns align to different date ranges, called PRE, DURING, POST. I'm able to get the columns created for the sum of the sales, but what I really want to be able to do is divide that sum by the distinct count of Month-Year combinations over the time period. For example, if the total sales during POST is $4,000 for a given customer, I'd like to be able to the return the average of $1,000 (4,000 divided by the 4 month/year combinations in the time period).

```
SELECT c.customer_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.date < '2021-04-01' THEN VALUE_USD END) PRE,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.date BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2022-03-31' THEN VALUE_USD END) DURING,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.date > '2022-04-01' THEN VALUE_USD END) POST
FROM SALES as s
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER as c
ON s.account_no = c.account_no
GROUP BY c.customer_name;
```

| customer.name | date | VALUE_USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 4/1/21 | 450 |
| JOHN SMITH | 7/1/21 | 100 |
| JOHN SMITH | 5/1/21 | 50 |
| JOHN SMITH | 5/3/21 | 100 |
| JOHN SMITH | 3/1/20 | 100 |
| JOHN SMITH | 4/1/20 | 100 |
| JOHN SMITH | 5/1/20 | 100 |
| JOHN SMITH | 5/1/22 | 500 |
| JOHN SMITH | 6/1/22 | 100 |

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: This would be a lot more clear if you showed us sample data and expected outcome

Comment: I recommend adding `ELSE 0` to each `CASE` to make sure the non-matching cases return a number (zero) so the `SUM` won't fail because its not all numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't just a conditional `AVG` work?

Comment: @GuidoG just added that info. sorry, just getting started with sql/stack.

Comment: Can you add the information as text, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @BrechtSanders in this case having a NULL would not matter. If you sum multiple values it will simply ignore any NULL values. But I also always like to be explicit. ;)

Comment: @GuidoG yes. I have now made that edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved by putting the case statements inside the `AVG` function in stead of `SUM`

```
SELECT s.customername,
       avg(CASE WHEN s.date < '2021-04-01' THEN VALUE_USD END) as AVG_PRE,
       avg(CASE WHEN s.date BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2022-03-31' THEN VALUE_USD END) as AVG_DURING,
       avg(CASE WHEN s.date > '2022-04-01' THEN VALUE_USD END) as AVG_POST
FROM test as s
GROUP BY s.customername
```

the result is

| customername | AVG_PRE | AVG_DURING | AVG_POST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 100 | 200 | 300 |

See [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a08dab55ad98e4ef6bae23f5f3bf226a) for more details

**EDIT** ( corrected thanks to helpfull comment of @TN )

After your edit, I altered my query and came up with this

```
select t.customername,
       avg(t.AVG_PRE) as AVG_PRE,
       avg(t.AVG_DURING) as AVG_DURING,
       avg(t.AVG_POST) as AVG_POST
from   ( SELECT s.customername,
                sum(CASE WHEN s.date < '2021-04-01' THEN VALUE_USD END) as AVG_PRE,
                sum(CASE WHEN s.date BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2022-03-31' THEN VALUE_USD END) as AVG_DURING,
                sum(CASE WHEN s.date > '2022-04-01' THEN VALUE_USD END) as AVG_POST
         FROM test as s
         GROUP BY s.customername, datepart(year, s.[date]), datepart(month, s.[date])
       ) t
GROUP BY t.customername
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f1b8cd21c14271d8fbacfbbc9d21a95)

That will give me this result

| customername | AVG_PRE | AVG_DURING | AVG_POST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 100.000000 | 233.333333 | 300.000000 |

Comment: Thanks. This is close, but if I add an additional row of data for the same month, it doesn't quite get me what I need. If you add a row like : ('JOHN SMITH', '5/3/21', 150), I would expect only the numerator to change in the calculation, not the denominator.

Comment: Than why did you not include that in your sample data and expected outcome ? I worked with the data you shared

Comment: I've now updated the sample data and desired output to reflect this.

Comment: Can you also explain in detail how you got to 233.3333

Comment: The above posted fiddle has data different from the OP. The following has corrected data and the expected result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7b37ddec6e50b51b86e4b657f381fa1 (Well close... Need to change the data to something other than integer to get the fractional part.)

Comment: @TN Well the data was correct then until he changed it, thanks for telling me about it. That explains how I could not make it to 233.3